# Issue while counting members in result set

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am into an interesting issue. I have a dimension called Product with hierarchy Product as 
**Rolodex1->Rolodex2->Rolodex3->Product ID**.

I am trying to create a calculated measure [**Product Count**] to count the number of "Product ID" members (lowest level) under selection.

My measure looks like:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Product Count] AS                                         
    COUNT(
      FILTER( 
         EXISTING [Product].[Product].[Product ID].MEMBERS
       , NOT ISEMPTY( [Measures].[Distinct Product Count] ) ))
)
```

[Distinct Product Count] is distinct count of Product ID. It should be 1 for existing Product ID's in selection.

The measure works when I select 2 members from same level and combine together and put in where condition. For eg it works on following query:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Product].[Product].[All Products].[Aggregation] AS 
  ' AGGREGATE( 
       { [Product].[Product].[Rolodex1].&[44], 
         [Product].[Product].[Rolodex1].&[45] }
   ) ' 
 SELECT 
   { [Measures].[Product Count] } ON COLUMNS ,   
   { [Paid Date].[Paid Date].[Paid Quarters].&[2016 - Q2]
    ,[Paid Date].[Paid Date].[Paid Quarters].&[2016 - Q3]  } ON ROWS     
 FROM [MyCube]   
 WHERE ( [Product].[Product].[All Products].[Aggregation] )
```

But it doesn't work with the following query when 2 **members from different levels** are selected and combined together:

```
WITH       
MEMBER [Product].[Product].[All Products].[Aggregation1] AS 
    ' AGGREGATE( 
        GENERATE( 
           FILTER( 
             { [Product].[Product].[Rolodex1].&[44], 
               [Product].[Product].[Rolodex2].&[4505] }
           , NOT ISEMPTY( 
               [Product].[Product].CURRENTMEMBER 
             )
           ), 
         HEAD( 
           HIERARCHIZE( 
             INTERSECT( 
              { [Product].[Product].[Rolodex1].&[44]
              , [Product].[Product].[Rolodex2].&[4505] } 
             ,ASCENDANTS( [Product].[Product].CURRENTMEMBER )
             )
            )
          )
         )
       ) '  
SELECT 
   { [Measures].[Product Count] } ON COLUMNS ,   
   { 
      [Paid Date].[Paid Date].[Paid Quarters].&[2016 - Q2]
     ,[Paid Date].[Paid Date].[Paid Quarters].&[2016 - Q3]  } ON ROWS     
FROM [Cost and Utilization]    
WHERE ( [Product].[Product].[All Products].[Aggregation1] )
```

The MDX for calculated members generated here [Product].[Product].[All Products].[Aggregation1] is the query generated by Proclarity when I select 2 members from different levels and combine together.

Please help. Has anybody encountered this issue before?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Initial advice is to use the following more efficient pattern for your measure:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Product Count] AS                                         
    SUM(
       EXISTING [Product].[Product].[Product ID].MEMBERS
       IIF (
         NOT ISEMPTY( [Measures].[Distinct Product Count] )
         ,1
         ,NULL
        )
     )
```

An alternative to the Proclarity script might be the following - does this return the result you expect?

```
WITH       
MEMBER [Product].[Product].[All Products].[Aggregation1] AS 
    ' AGGREGATE(
        EXISTS( 
          [Product].[Product].[Product ID].MEMBERS
         ,{ [Product].[Product].[Rolodex1].&[44]
          , [Product].[Product].[Rolodex2].&[4505] } 
         )
       ) '  
SELECT 
   { [Measures].[Product Count] } ON COLUMNS ,   
   { 
      [Paid Date].[Paid Date].[Paid Quarters].&[2016 - Q2]
     ,[Paid Date].[Paid Date].[Paid Quarters].&[2016 - Q3]  } ON ROWS     
FROM [Cost and Utilization]    
WHERE ( [Product].[Product].[All Products].[Aggregation1] )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried modifying the measure with the one you suggested. But no luck. Same result. It is still considering all [Product].[Product].[Product ID].MEMBERS into account while calculating Product Count.

Comment: MEMBER [Product].[Product].[All Products].[Aggregation1] AS 
    ' AGGREGATE(
       { [Product].[Product].[Rolodex1].&[44]
          , [Product].[Product].[Rolodex2].&[4505] } 
         )
       )

Comment: The above MDX for Aggregation1 works. But since we create sets with proclarity, I will have to come with the logic that works with MDX when sets are created from proclarity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by using a dynamic set to hold the product id's under selection. Please let me know if anyone needs specific answer. I will provide all the details. Thank you.